# Removing favorites only works on the first page

Tags: bug, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t De-Favorite from my profile after favorites are reloaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15533/cant-de-favorite-from-my-profile-after-favorites-are-reloaded)

You can remove favorites from the list in the profile simply by clicking the star again...unfortunately, this only works for the first page of the favorites. On any subsequent page, clicking the star does nothing.