# Defavoriting questions from the favorites page doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

Steps to reproduce (assuming you have at least one favorited question):

1. Go to your user page.
2. Click on the favorites tab.
3. Click on one of the yellow stars. It turns white, and that question's favorite count is decremented.
4. Press F5 on your keyboard or select View->Reload in your browser.
5. The white star changes to a yellow star, and the favorite count is reverted to its original value.

Comment: Using Firefox 3.5.9 / Windows Vista SP1.

Comment: Crazy.  I've tried to unfave this way but never followed up to see if it _really_ worked.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

My bad - this will be fixed in tonight's deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced - FF 3.6.3 on XP SP3

I traced it through Fiddler and no ajax request was logged.  Same javascript error as ccomet got.

Answer (score 1):

Occurs for me using IE8 on XP. I saw a nice "Error loading page", and checked to see the following error report.

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152)
>   Timestamp: Thu, 10 Jun 2010 17:50:31 UTC
>
> Message: 'fkey' is undefined
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 2553
>   Code: 0
>   URI: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/question.js?v=cc6b2d7ff15f

**UPDATE**

It seems that this may be related to the [recent fix implemented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15533/cant-de-favorite-from-my-profile-after-favorites-are-reloaded). Nick Craver's script includes a term "fkey", so it might be caused by some part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced with Firefox 3.6.3 Ubuntu with Firebug on SO:

```
fkey is not defined
http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=cc6b2d7ff15f
Line 1
```

Seemed to work fine when doing the same from the actual question page.